# Pythonic way of slicing 2-d numpy arrays into smaller squares

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to handle a RAW image using numpy.

Printing the raw image numpy array returns this:

```
[[372 387 247 ... 560 359 364]
 [380 392 243 ... 599 342 356]
 [236 238 358 ... 355 600 564]
 ...
 [547 553 344 ...  74  69  69]
 [349 328 560 ...  68  74  73]
 [341 334 537 ...  70  71  73]]
```

with shape `4384, 5632`.

I want to obtain a list of lists (2D list), such that each entry will correspond to a `8 * 8` square of the 2d numpy array.

This would indicate a list of dimensions `4384/8 , 5632/8`.

I can only think of using while loops and appending each square into the list at the moment, but I was thinking there must be a better way.

Is there a more pythonic way of doing it, maybe using list comprehension and slicing?

Comment: Please try below to see whether it give you the desired result.

rawimg.reshape(-1,8,8)

Comment: `print(rawimg.reshape([-1,8,8])[0])` gives different results from `print(rawimg[0][0:8])` and `print(rawimg[1][0:8])`, where the first two lines of the first statement should look the same as the results of the latter :( Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please try below code:

rawimg.reshape(rawimg.shape[0]//8, 8, -1, 8).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1, 8, 8)

Comment: Oh wow, that works like a charm. Can you explain how that works? I'd like to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a short explanation of the answer

```
# 1.  Reshape Image as (height/8, 8, width/8,8)
print(rawimg.reshape(rawimg.shape[0]//8, 8, -1, 8).shape)
# 2. Swap 1 and 2nd index
print(rawimg.reshape(rawimg.shape[0]//8, 8, -1, 8).swapaxes(1,2).shape)
# 3. Reshape again (-1,8,8) with -1 being combined both (548*704) arrays of shape 8x8
print(rawimg.reshape(rawimg.shape[0]//8, 8, -1, 8).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,8,8).shape)


(548, 8, 704, 8)
(548, 704, 8, 8)
(385792, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted the result to be a 2d list of 8x8 array as well. So I think step two can be the final! Thanks anyway for the solution :)